# PWM in 8051 with PCA counter

Tags: pwm, assembly, 8051

I read in documentation of AT89C51RC2, that I can make one of 5 ports to generate PWM signal if I set properly some registers. Some things I don't understand. I don't know what PCA counter is and how it behaves. There is what I came up with according to documentation.

```
CEX0 equ P1.3                   
CCAPM0 equ 0DAh                 
CCAP0L equ 0EAh                 
CCAP0H equ 0FAh
CL equ 0E9h
CCON equ 0D8h


DSEG at 30h   

CSEG                

    ORG 0000h               
    AJMP START

START:  
    MOV CCAPM0,#10000010B
    MOV CCAP0H,#0FFh
    MOV CCAP0L,#0FFh
    ORL CCON,#01000000B

MAIN:  

    MOV R6,#0FFh        
    DJNZ R6,$   

    MOV A,01000000B
    XRL A,CCON
    JNZ null 

 LJMP MAIN          

 null:
    MOV CL,#0
    MOV CCON,#01000000B
    LJMP MAIN 

END
```

I don't know which direction the CPA counter counts, whether it is needed to reset it, I don't know If I forgot to set some registers. This code doesn't work. Looks like the counter doesn't even count.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Another one register is needed to set.

```
CMOD equ 0D9h
```

[image]

I need to set mode of the PCA counter and  enable Counter Overflow Interrupt. So the code goes

```
CEX0 equ P1.3                   
CCAPM0 equ 0DAh                 
CCAP0L equ 0EAh                 
CCAP0H equ 0FAh
CL equ 0E9h
CCON equ 0D8h
CMOD equ 0D9h


DSEG at 30h                     

CSEG                

    ORG 0000h               
    AJMP START


START:  
    MOV SP,#70H             
    SETB EA                 ; global interrupt enable
    MOV CCAPM0,#10000010B    
    MOV CCAP0H,#0FFh     
    MOV CCAP0L,#0FFh        
    ORL CCON,#01000000B
    ANL CMOD,#11111001B     ; PCA counter mode 0
    ORL CMOD,#00000001B     ; PCA counter interrupt enable

MAIN:  

MOV

    R6,#0FFh        ;delay, because I use serial to change duty cycle, 
    DJNZ R6,$       ;so it had time to change


    MOV A,01000000B
    XRL A,CCON
    JNZ null 

 LJMP MAIN               

 null:
    MOV CL,#0
    MOV CCON,#01000000B
    LJMP MAIN 

END
```

I can see it's working with voltmeter or LED attached to port P1.3.

Comment: The CL counter and overFlow flag in CCON doesn't need to be reset in code. It works without it.